# How to Wget images from CSV, append url and filenames from fields?

Tags: bash, wget, csv

I have a CSV with 4 fields (id1,id2,id3,filename) like this:

```
2,2314,78,/image/1289.jpg
1,19825,179,/image/01288.jpg
2,2585,2281,/image/01287.jpg
3,35879,82,/image/01286.jpg
```

There is a common URL endpoint for the images like

> ```
> http://example.com/assets/?mediafile=
> ```

The last column is the unique portion of the URL to the image.

I'm trying to download each image, and name of each image is based on the first 3 fields:

id1 is always 1 digit
id2 is really 5 digits with prepending zeros (so 2314 needs to become 02314)
id3 is really 4 digits (78 becomes 0078),

so in total a 10 digit code.
So the first image name should be 2023140078.jpg

If I were to download a single file manually, I'd do something like this:

```
wget -O 2023140078.jpg http://example.com/assets/?mediafile=/image/1289.jpg
```

Also if I could write back some sort of status or error code to the row or write an error log, would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk -F, '{printf("%d%.5d%.4d %s\n",$1,$2,$3,$4)}' input.csv | while read newfile filename 
do 
wget -O "${newfile}.jpg" http://example.com/assets/?mediafile=${filename} 
done
```

Comment: After running this for 200,000 rows I realized that not all filenames are unique, and some IDs have several images, how can I fix this?

Comment: what you mean by its not unique ? are you ok to add the incremental value in the filename ? eg: 2023140078_1.jpg 2023140078_2.jpg ..... 2023140078_200000.jpg

Comment: Some of the entries have several URLs for the same filename so wget is downloading them all, replacing the first file with the next. Most have only 1 file, but some have several. I'd like for the 1st to stay in the original format and the rest add _1 etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `IFS` to a comma and use a `while` loop to read the 4 variables that uses the file as input:

```
IFS=','
while read c1 c2 c3 c4; do
  wget -O "$(printf "%d%05d%04d.jpg" "$c1" "$c2" "$c3")" "http://example.com/assets/?mediafile=${c4}"
done < file.txt
```

Comment: if second column has the value of 12345, then the filename will be created with 11 digit

Comment: Sorry, I misread your padding requirements. You can use printf command substitution for that:

$ IFS=','; while read c1 c2 c3 c4; do echo wget -O "${c1}$(printf %05d ${c2})$(printf %04d ${c3})" "http://example.com/assets/?mediafile=${c4}"; done < file.txt

Comment: You should [edit] your answer to improve it.  Comments are often overlooked and sometimes deleted. And you don't need two `printf`s; just do `$(printf "%d%05d%04d.jpg" "$c1" "$c2" "$c3")`.